# php sort array of object based on all object fields

Tags: php, arrays

I got the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 1
        [name] => NULL
        //...10 more fields here
        [count] => NULL
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 2
        [name] => NULL
        //...10 more fields here
        [count] => NULL
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 3
        [name] => NULL
        //...10 more fields here
        [count] => 4354
    )
[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 4
        [name] => Alice
        //...10 more fields here
        [count] => NULL
    )

....
```

So as you can see I got 1 and 2 elements where `name` and `count` (and all other fields that are not shown here) are `NULL` and the other elements where they are not `NULL`. I need to put all elements of the array which have ALL fields as `NULL` except `ID` (in this case 1 and 2) to the end of the array. How can I do that?

I tried to use `usort` but it sorts based on only one propery of the object. What if I need to count for several objects at once?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a `foreach` loop or `array_map` and manually push the values to end of the array?

Comment: any examples how this could be achieved?

Comment: *"I tried to use usort but it sorts based on only one propery of the object."* -- [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) sorts based on the comparison function you provide. Its entirely up to you what properties of the object you use for the comparison and how.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Apart from the elements that have both `NULL` as the value of `name` and `count`, how to sort the other elements?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the usort function: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Here is the code:

```
function your_comparison($a, $b) {
    if(($a->name or $a->count) and (!$b->name and !$b->count)) {
        return -1;
    } else if(($b->name or $b->count) and (!$a->name and !$a->count)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

usort($array, 'your_comparison');
```

Comment: Develop this into a complete answer (with code) and you'll get some up votes, maybe the answer will be accepted. Then you'll have [enough reputation to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Or I'll do it and I'll collect all the reputation you could have. :-D

Comment: and what if there are 10 more fields in the object except `name` and `count`. How could I check for them all?

Comment: @Masha it depens on Your needs, You can use cycle, whatever. Create Your own conditions to compare objects.

Comment: @Masha you can extend the object with method countFilledFields and sort them by the returned value. Or edit Your question to contain some sample objects, we can put something together. Hope you can accept my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `NULL` is minimum value, but if you want you can change the world

```
<?php

$arr =array(array('ID' => 1,
    'name' => NULL,
    'count' => NULL
    ),

array(

    'ID' => 2,
    'name' => NULL,
    'count' => NULL
    ),

array(

    'ID' => 3,
    'name' => NULL,
    'count' => 4354
    ),
array(

    'ID' => 4,
    'name' => 'Alice',
    'count' => NULL
    ),
);

function icmp($a, $b){
    return $a> $b ? 1 : ($a == $b ? 0 : -1);
}

function cmp($a,$b){ // $a,$b are reference to first index of array
    $res = icmp($a['ID'], $b['ID']);
    if($res == 0){
        $res = $a['name']==NULL ? 1: ($b['name'] == NULL ? -1 : strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]));
        if($res==0)
            $res = icmp($a['count'], $b['count']);
    }  
    return $res;
}
usort($arr, "cmp"); 

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: and what if I have 10 more fields, except `name` and `count`? do I need to write 10 `if` to check them all?